# If any, what class specific actions happen when declaring an empty object field of a given class in java?

Tags: java, object, null, dataflow

Imagine a hierachical set of Classes, where Class A has a field Class B, and Class B has field of Class C. The fields are set in the constructor of each class.

Now if I create an object instance of a Class X, with a field "a" of Class A, where "a" is never set, and remains null:

If any, what class specific "actions" happen from the object "a"? Will it call anything at all from it's own fields? Does Class B or C react at all? I imagine that there might be memory allocation or similar, but I am not sure at all. The reason why I am asking, is to get a better understanding of the data flow, and sequence of actions in applications.

I have tried to find an answer to this question for a while, but I can't seem to find the right way to ask, as the question is a little too close to basic questions about how to define objects in Java.

Comment: why don't you just write a little program with your classes and see what happens

Comment: Please write some code so we can quickly help you :)

Comment: There is no object "a", since the field is null. So how could "nothing" fire an event? Why do you think events are fired. There is no event fired at all. Class B and Class C can't "react", because classes are not living objects listening to anything.

Comment: @gefei Well, that is what I do in most cases, but here I cannot seem to come up with a solutiun which let's me physically see what the outcome is. Although having a bit of experience, I have a lot to learn, and I am not sure how to check if an object is granted i.e. Memory allocation

Comment: @JB Nizet Seems like a valid point. I would love to find somewhere to read more about this though, if it even exists. Maybe the question is too obvious for most programmers.

Comment: What do you mean by event firing? How objects can fire events? Do you mean to say - can reference of class A, i.e. "a" can do anything?

Comment: @Meraman Yes, that is a better way of putting it. In my view, "a" represents a container for an instance of A. So when defining this empty container "a", does it in any way register that it contains a field of B, and therefore memory allocates for it, or any other actions/events or happenings that is related to the underlying fields? I've edited the question to put it more like your question.

Comment: Yes, as you have reference of A in class X, object of X will have memory allocated to hold A reference. But as you are not creating object of A, nothing can be allocated as objects for A or B or C.

Comment: @KjetilNordin  "a" is not a container for an instance of A. It is a container for reference to an instance. References for all objects, as well as nulls, are values of length 32 or 64 bits - just like an int or long int. Memory is allocated when an object is created with `new`, and not when a reference returned by `new` is written to a variable. No `new` - no memory allocation.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov There I go! That was the answer i needed to fully understand a question I had trouble specifying. Thank you very much, you just taught me something new. I would love to mark it as an answer, but the question itself might not make enough sense to keep here. If you think it'll be of any help to others, write your comment as an answer.

Comment: @KjetilNordin: In your special setup the classes `A`, `B`, and `C` are not even get loaded (in most JVM implementations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So lets assume the following classes definition:

```
public class A {
    private B b;

    public A() {
        b = new B();
    }
}

public class B {
    private C c;

    public B() {
        c = new C();
    }
}

public class C {
    public C() {
    }
}

public class X {
    private A a;

    public X() {
    }
}
```

Now let assume that the following main is being executed:

```
public static final void main (String[] argv) {
    X x = new X();
}
```

Here an instance of `X` is create in the memory heap and a reference to this object is store in the `x` variable.

Since no value is assign to the `a` variable during the class construction, then no instance of A is created.  The `a` variable still takes up space in memory as part of the instance of `X` that was created (in other words, it still needs enough space to be able to store a reference), but in this case `a` is assigned the `null` value (from [Java Language Specification §4.12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5))

> For all reference types ([§4.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3)), the default value is null.

Now lets modify the `X` class as follow

```
public class X {
    private A a;

    public X() {
        a = new A();
    }
}
```

If we were to execute the `main()` method again with this modified version of `X`, then as part of the construction process, `X` would cause an instance of `A` to be created which would cause an instance of `B` to be created which in turn would cause an instance of class `C` to be created.  All these instances would take up space in the memory heap and the reference to these objects would be stored in their respective variables.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than thinking of reference-type variables as holding "pointers", I think it more helpful to think of them as holding object identifiers.  If `X` is a variable of class type `Thing`, then `X` holds either information sufficient to identify an instance of `Thing` or a class derived therefrom, or else information sufficient to say that it does not.  Although reference-type variables in many Java implementations hold pointers of some sort, there's no requirement that they do so.  A Java implementation which wanted to access more than four gigs of memory without having to use 64-bit object references could round all object sizes up to the next multiple of 16 bytes and then have each non-zero object reference store a scaled offset into the heap (so an object which is located 32016 bytes above the start of the heap would store the number "2001" [decimal] as a reference).  Although Java doesn't say what the bit pattern associated with a reference means, the one thing it does specify is that the bit pattern with which array slots and object fields are initialized will never identify any object.